# Changing img opacity with the use of css class in slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, image

I was following a tutorial to design a simple slider, I decided to mix some things and I encountered trouble. The slider tutorial was supposed to use the translate to slide images right and left, but I wanted to use a change in opacity values and stack images so I wouldn't need to use translate and maybe use a transition to smooth the effect at the opacity change. I accomplished the following with a div, but I'm having trouble using the same process with the images. This is what I accomplished so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/6nLx5/1/. The transition is supposed to happen at the moment you click the Image 1, image 2, Image 3 and Image 4 texts. The following is the css for the selected images

```
img_selected{
    z-index:+11;
    -webkit-opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 12s ease;
    transition: opacity 2s ease;
}
```

The following code is for the unselected images within the slider.

```
.slider-photos img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.0;
    -moz-opacity: 0.0;
    opacity: 0.0;
    z-index:+10;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 3s ease;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

Images are at opacity 0 since the class activation with jquery was supposed to make them visible, at the moment the class was toggled. Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem of specifity. img_selected has lower specifity than .slider-photos img so the opacity of the later is the "winner".

You can solve that adding important in the selected property:

```
.img_selected {
    z-index:+11;
    opacity: 1 !important;
```

This is a non-popular way of solving it, I know, but it is the faster and easy one.
The more accepted way would be to set a more specific selector, as

```
.slider-photos img.img_selected {
    opacity: 1;
```

### [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6267b/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this made me crazy for days. Provided two possible answers that worked :) thanks.